# Threads in service not working properly

Tags: android, multithreading, api, handler

I have created a service in android which is running two thread simultaneously one after every 30 sec and another after every 5 minutes. booth of them calling api.
till my phone is connected to the system to watch logs it works fine but as i disconnect phone from system 5 minutes thread start misbehaving it doesn't execute ask after every 5 minutes.

Here's my code.

```
if (fivemiuntesHandler == null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started five minutes ..............: ");
            fivemiuntesHandler = new Handler();

            fivemiuntesHandler.postDelayed(fiveminutes, 300000);

        }

        if (thirtysecHandler == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started five minutes ..............: "); 
            thirtysecHandler = new Handler();
            thirtysecHandler.postDelayed(thirtySec, 0);

        }


private Runnable fiveminutes  = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user_detail",
                    MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            login_id = sharedPreferences.getString("login_id", "");
            url = sharedPreferences.getString("url", "");

            responseArray= null;
            response= null;
            try {

                URL URl;

                byte[] data;

                String lat_current_pos = null, lng_current_pos = null,address_base64 = null,lat_base64,lng_base64;



                    lat_current_pos = lat;
                    lng_current_pos=lng;





                data = gcm_id.getBytes("UTF-8");
                String gcm_base64 = Base64.encode(data);
                data = login_id.getBytes("UTF-8");
                String login_base64 = Base64.encode(data);


                if(Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE)!=0 && Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE) !=1){
                    data = getAddress(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat_current_pos), Double.valueOf(lng_current_pos))).getBytes("UTF-8");
                    address_base64  = Base64.encode(data);
                    }else
                    {

                        data = "LOCATION_MODE_OFF".getBytes("UTF-8");
                        address_base64 = Base64.encode(data);


                    }

                if(Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE)==0 || Settings.Secure.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE)==1)
                {

                    data = "".getBytes("UTF-8");
                    lat_base64 = Base64.encode(data);
                    data = "".getBytes("UTF-8");
                    lng_base64 = Base64.encode(data);

                }else{
                data = lat_current_pos.getBytes("UTF-8");
                 lat_base64 = Base64.encode(data);
                data = lng_current_pos.getBytes("UTF-8");
                 lng_base64 = Base64.encode(data);

                }
                data = name.getBytes("UTF-8");
                String name_base64 = Base64.encode(data);

                data = "I".getBytes("UTF-8");
                String flag_base64 = Base64.encode(data);



                    URl = new URL(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.services_push_lat_lng));



                List<NameValuePair> liNameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login_id",
                        login_base64));
                liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gcm_id", gcm_base64));
                if(address_base64==null)
                {
                liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", ""));
                }else
                    liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address", address_base64));    
                liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat_base64));
                liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lon", lng_base64));
                liNameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name_base64));
                if (url.contains("boss.xsinfosol.com")) {
                    liNameValuePairs
                            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("flag", flag_base64));

                }
                ApiCallingclass apiCallingclass = new ApiCallingclass();
                    responseArray = apiCallingclass.callApi(liNameValuePairs, URl);
                response = responseArray[0];
                System.out.println("5 minutes " + response +"  "+login_id);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();

            }



            fivemiuntesHandler.postDelayed(fiveminutes, 300000);



        }
    };


private Runnable thirtySec = new Runnable() {



        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            update_current_location_tracker uLocation_tracker = new update_current_location_tracker();
            uLocation_tracker.execute();


            thirtysecHandler.postDelayed(thirtySec, 30000);

        }

    };
```

So please help me out from this.

Comment: try to set your service    exported = "true", by setting this your service work in its own process just like a app independently , hopefully then you will not get this error.

Comment: Please note that runnables with handlers are not run in a separate thread. They are still in the thread of the service

Comment: You may check if there is any error on the stack from the 5 min handler. Runtime errors such as null pointers might not be caught by your try-catch block.  Or try post delay in a `finally` block.  In general, as explained in the answer below, you should use alarm for longer term recurring jobs.

Comment: @headuck Alarm Manager doesn't repeat the task after executing it once in Kit-Kat and above

Answer (score 1):

"till my phone is connected to the system to watch logs it works fine but as i disconnect phone..."

The problem is that while you are connected to a dev system, the device is charging and (generally) won't go into a full sleep state. This is especially true if you have the dv option enabled to keep the device on when connected over USB. Once you disconnect from the dev system, Android gets very aggressive about power management and will go into a sleep state. Your threads will not run until the device comes up long enough to give them CPU time, which is indeterminate.

Use `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` to set recurring operations and coordinate with power management.

Comment: Yes ,you are right i am getting same  prob but few days ago it was working fine and now it's not.....Alarm Manager doesn't repeat the task after executing task once. So please tell me how to run thread in service even when phone is in sleep mode.

Comment: `AlarmManager` can do repeating tasks (see the methods `setInexactRepeating()` and `setRepeating()`).  You cannot run a thread within a `Service` while in sleep mode.  By definition the phone is asleep and nothing is running on the CPU.  `AlarmManager` and/or `JobScheduler` are your best options.  Even using `AlarmManager`, you'll need to coordinate your code using a wake lock so that you guarantee your `Service` code executes.

Comment: I just face issue in the thread which is running after 5 minutes and the thread which runs after  every 30 sec is working fine.

In Alarm Manager setRepeating() and setInexactRepeating() does not work in kit-kat and above

Comment: The repeating alarms will work in Kit-Kat, they will just be in-exact.  So they will not run exactly at 5 minutes.  The system tries to batch them with other alarms and they could miss *an entire interval*.  With durations this short, I wouldn't be surprised if it goes longer than that.  Starting with Marshmallow, even this will not work as-is if the device is in doze mode.  In general, it's considered bad practice to be running this frequently if the user's device is not actively being used as it negatively impacts battery life.

Comment: If you are using alarms, be sure to use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` in order to receive the alarm.  Have it trigger your `Service`.  You need the wakelock in order to keep the device awake long enough to trigger your service to do something, then have the service release the wakelock (via the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent()`.